# Calculating the instantaneous position of an object constant speed and varying direction

Tags: calculus

Given an initial position for an object that's moving at constant speed but with a direction that varies in a linear fashion over time, how can I calculate the instantaneous position of the object?

For example, if an object is moving a 2 km/h, with an initial position of (0,0), an initial direction of 0° and a final direction of 90° over a  period of 1 hour, how can I get it's position at any point during that hour?

Please bear in mind that I'm a programmer, not a mathematician! With that in mind, I have no idea what to tag this question with....

Comment: I presume that there's a unique solution; spirals and circles come to my mind.

Comment: I hope there's a unique solution!

Comment: Is the angle change uniform or is it determined by some function?

Comment: The change is uniform.

Comment: I found the following expression for the displacement of the object that starts at $(0,0)$, it is: $d(t)=(d_x,d_y)=\frac{4}{\pi} (\sin(\frac{\pi t}{2}), 1-\cos(\frac{\pi t}{2}))$. I can edit this into an answer with derivation if you are interested!

Comment: @teun Yes please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean that the angle goes from start angle to final angle at a constant rate, the object traces out a **circular arc.**

You can prove this by writing out the differential equations and solving them.  I won't give a proof, however, because it doesn't seem like you are necessarily looking for one.  Instead, I'll just give some general details about the arc traced by the object.

Suppose $\theta_0$ is the initial angle, $\theta_1$ is the final angle, $T$ is the total time between the two angles, and $V$ is the constant velocity.  Then:

- The angle at any given time $t$ is $\theta(t) = \theta_0 + \frac{t}{T} (\theta_1 - \theta_0)$.
- Assuming the angles are **in radians**, the radius of the circle traced out is $R = \frac{VT}{\theta_1 - \theta_0}$.
  This follows from that the distance traveled is $R(\theta_1 - \theta_0)$, so the velocity must be $V = \frac{R\theta_1 - \theta_0}{T}$; then just solve for $R$.
- If the object starts at $(0,0)$, the center of the circle is at $(R\cos(\theta_0 + 90^\circ), R\sin(\theta_0 + 90^\circ))$.  (Adding $90^\circ$ to the angle $\theta_0$ gives us the direction from the object to the circle's center.)
  This simplifies to $(-R\sin \theta_0, R \cos \theta_0)$.
- The displacement from the center of the circle to the object at any time is $(-R \cos(\theta + 90^\circ), - R \sin(\theta +90^\circ))$, where as above $\theta$ depends on $t$.  This simplifies to $(R \sin \theta, - R \cos \theta)$.

To get the position of the object (in $(x,y)$ coordinates) at a general time $t$ just add the center of the circle and the displacement together:
$$
\Big(x(t), y(t)\Big) = ( R\sin \theta - R\sin \theta_0, -R\cos \theta + R\cos \theta_0 )
$$
You can of course factor out the $R$ if you want.

**Clarification**

Regarding the limit as $\theta_1 - \theta_0 \to 0$, consider the $x$-coordinate:
$$
R (\sin \theta - \sin \theta_0) = VT \frac{\sin \theta - \sin \theta_0}{\theta_1 - \theta_0}
= VT \frac{\sin \left((\theta_0 + \frac{t}{T} (\theta_1 - \theta_0)\right) - \sin \theta_0}{\theta_1 - \theta_0}
$$

Write $\theta_1 - \theta_0 = \Delta$.
The limit as $\Delta$ goes to zero may be found by recognizing the definition of the derivative:
$$
x(t) = \lim_{\Delta \to 0} VT \frac{\sin \left((\theta_0 + \frac{t}{T} \Delta\right) - \sin \theta_0}{\Delta} = VT \left( \frac{t}{T} \cos(\theta_0) \right) = Vt\cos\theta_0
$$

Similarly one may compute $y(t) = Vt\sin\theta_0$.   Hence the object is just traveling in a straight line in direction $\theta_0$ with velocity $V$ (as expected).

Comment: Hi. The angle at a given time makes complete sense. For the radius I'll just accept that without question :) However, I can't see how I can find the center of the circle in relation to the starting position, in order to work out the end position.

Comment: I don't know if this changes much, but what I actually *need* is the point's translation over that time.

Comment: @tarmes I've added a couple bullets, does this help?

Comment: Something's not right. In testing I had the case that \theta_0 and \theta_1 are the same, which results in an infinite radius. Although that's to be expected, it made me realise that in the case where there's a tiny variance, the radius is gigantic, and this results in an enormous displacement, which clearly isn't right....

Comment: @tarmes The formula is correct.  As the difference between $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$ gets smaller, the time $T$ should also get smaller - in this case the radius will stay the same.  But if you keep the time and velocity constant, and only change $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$, that means the object is traveling the same distance, but only decreasing in how much its angle changes.  Thus the radius will go to infinity.

Comment: If I go back to to my example, and change it such that we move at 2km/h, for an hour, with a change in theta of 0° (no change of direction), then I'd expect to see a displacement of 2km. Your formula gives me an infinite displacement at the limit of 0°.

Comment: @tarmes My formula for displacement is from the center of the circle.  Indeed when the change in theta approaches 0 degrees, the circle's center approaches infinite, so the displacement from the circle's center is infinite.  If you add the circle's center to the displacement as I suggest, the limit will not be infinity.

Comment: I just realized I've typoed and I meant 90 degrees or $\pi/2$ when I said $\pi$.  Fail.  Fixing now, and further simplifying the formulas, and clarifying...

Comment: Sorry for all the confusion and errors in my answer!  I hope everything is fixed now.  Please let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I appreciate all your help, it just seems that we're not quite understanding each other. Consider a change of heading from 0 to 0.00001 degrees over 1 hour at 2km/h: R = 2/0.00001 = 200000. x(t) for theta = 0.00001 = R (sin(0) - sin(0.00001)) = -0.035.It should be approx. 2.

Comment: @tarmes, in that case $x(t) = R(\sin \theta - \sin \theta_0) = 200000 (\sin(0.00001) - \sin(0)) = 2.00000...$.  See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=200000%28sin%280.00001%29+-+sin%280%29%29

Comment: Ah :)  I have a bug somewhere then. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

We are looking for $d(t)=(d_x(t),d_y(t))$, and we will need an expression for $v(t)=(v_x(t),v_y(t))$ to find it. If we consider the direction of the velocity with respect to the x-axis (call the angle $\theta$) we find that $\tan(\theta)=\frac{v_y}{v_x}$, or 
$$v_y =v_x\tan (\theta)$$
We are given that the direction of the velocity changes linearly so
$$\frac{d\theta}{d t}=c$$
for some constant $c$, giving as a solution $\theta = ct + \theta_0$. Here $\theta_0$ is the direction of the initial velocity. Now if we use this expression in our expression for $v_y$ we find:
$$v_y = v_x \tan(ct+\theta_0)$$
We also know that the magnitude of the velocity is equal to $V$ at all times. This magnitude is given by:
$$\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2} = \sqrt{ v_x^2(1+\tan^2(ct+\theta_0))    }=\frac{v_x}{\cos(ct)+\theta_0}=V$$
Here we use $\sqrt{ (1+\tan^2(ct+\theta_0)} =\frac{1}{\cos(ct+\theta_0)}$ which is easily deduced from $sin^2+cos^2=1$.

Now we have:
$$v_x=\cos(ct+\theta_0)V$$
and thus 
$$v_y = v_x \tan(ct+\theta_0)=\sin(ct+\theta_0)V$$
We can find $c$ from $\theta = ct+\theta_0$. For this we will need the direction of the velocity, $\theta_1$ at some $t_1$. these must be specified before hand or we cannot solve for $c$. Then we have, after rearranging, $c=\frac{\theta_1-\theta_0}{t_1}$. With $V$ assumed constant we now have $v(t)=(v_x(t),v_y(t))$:
$$v(t)= \left(V\cos \left(\frac{\theta_1-\theta_0}{t_1}\cdot t +\theta_0 \right) , V\sin \left(\frac{\theta_1-\theta_0}{t_1}\cdot t + \theta_0\right)\right)$$
to find the displacement we integrate the velocity from the initial time to some time $t$:
$$d(t) - d(0) = \int\limits_{0}^{t} \left(V\cos \left(\frac{\theta_1-\theta_0}{t_1}\cdot s  + \theta_0 \right) , V\sin \left(\frac{\theta_1-\theta_0}{t_1}\cdot s + \theta_0\right)\right)ds = V \left[\frac{t_1}{\theta_1-\theta_0}\sin \left(\frac{\theta_1-\theta_0}{t_1}\cdot t  + \theta_0\right) , -\frac{t_1}{\theta_1-\theta_0}\cos \left(\frac{\theta_1-\theta_0}{t_1}\cdot t  + \theta_0\right)\right]_{t=0}^{t=t}$$
Here we used the fact that $d(0)=(0,0)$. Finally, this equals:
$$d(t) = \frac{V t_1}{\theta_1-\theta_0} \left(       \sin\left(  \frac{\theta_1-\theta_0}{t_1}\cdot t  + \theta_0 \right) - \sin(\theta_0),  -\cos\left(  \frac{\theta_1-\theta_0}{t_1}\cdot t  + \theta_0 \right) +\cos(\theta_0) \right)$$

Just as a side note, in your example $\theta_0 = 0$, $\theta_1=\frac{\pi}{2}$, $t_1=1$ and $V=2$. When you use these in the final equation for the displacement you will find a much easier expression.

Comment: Well, I'd certainly not have managed that, thanks! There's a problem though, you've solved the example case, not the general one...

Comment: Will update, with general you mean with initial displacement not equal to zero, $V$ unknown and unknown $\theta_0$? still constant change in direction though?

Comment: Yes. Looking at your solution, and thinking intuitively, it seems that the translated position at time t is simply given by the distance travelled in at time t in the direction of the instantaneous angle at time t. Does that sounds right?

Comment: (Actually, the initial position can be considered to be (0, 0) since it's the x and y deltas that I need)

Comment: I have updated the answer to a general case, it looks a lot more complicated and cluttered, feel free to let me know if things are unclear!

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you mean by translation. I guess the object undergoes a translation in both the $x$ and $y$ direction. These are given by the displacement in this case because the initial displacement is zero. The displacement of course has two components in this case, giving you the displacement in both directions.